# Crashing if user touches screen after I call startActivity(i);

Tags: android

I have a app that has a home button that exicutes the following code

```
void GoHome()
{
    mPreesedHome=true;
    Intent i;   
    i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

If the user does nothing it, works fine, but it takes nearly 15 seconds to go back to home screen and if user touches the screen it will crash.

I tried to have a flag set, so if the `GoHome()` method were to be called, the `onTouchEvent` would exit

Example:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (mPreesedHome)
        return true;
```

I set a breakpoint and this does work; I'm stuck.

Comment: could you post LOGCAT when crashing??

Comment: initialise mPressedHome = false before void goHome method and set mPressedHome = true inside the goHome method.